# isdgit with floats and decimal

Tags: python

So I have defined a string function using `isdigit`. The function is supposed to return true for positive numbers and false for words and negative numbers. But true for numbers with decimals. I realize `isdigit` already checks for numbers that are positive but it does not allow decimal usage.

I cannot post my code because it is an assignment I just wanted some help with this. I cannot use `try` and `except`. For example my return is just `isdigit`, it works for positive and none numbers (words), however It doesn't work for decimals. I'm trying to make it only for real decimals like `1.2` and `44.2` not like `22.22.22`. What can I do without using `try` and `except`?

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: return (s.isdecimal())

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put important details like that there.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is not a digit, so if a string contains one, the `.isdigit()` method returns `False`. You could remove the first occurance before checking like `foo.replace(".", "", count=1).isdigit()`. For more complex string pattern checks, you'll want to use the `re` module, which could be used to specify arbitrary number formats using a regular expression.